# case sensitive use of federation Id at logon

Tags: single-sign-on

Our Active Directory system is NOT case sensitive respect of the federation ID. So, if for a user the true federation id is  myID  a person could also use  Myid. We notice, however that Salesforce is -by default- case sensitive respect of the federation Id.

Is it possible to change this behavior within Salesforce?

Any special setting?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a known issue -- or other people are having the problem
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lB3CAAU

Salesforce does have 18 digit case insensitive versions of all their IDs so this seems like it would be something that should be doable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hope Salesforce will arrange this situation as this is forcing me to implement code in the createUser method to detect and compare the entered federationId and the existent one in the database for uppercase and lowercase characters. This is forcing me to also update the respective user info with the entered fedId to allow the user to login.

Comment: Sounds like a pain! Hope they fix it for ya soon.

Comment: I'm happy to say that as of Summer '20 this issue is now resolved and there is a setting to make federation IDs case-insensitive.